# JQuery DataTables Pagination Text Display Is Off

Tags: jquery, joomla, datatables, joomla3.5

I have set-up the JQuery DataTables on my site, however the text for Search and Records per page is displaying off.  This image shows how the demo on the site shows it will be displayed
[image: Should Be]

however, when I have everything set-up on my site, this is the display that I get[image]

What do I need to change so that my site displays the same as the demo?

**Edit**
This is the syntax I am using to populate the HTML table

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT vendorname, vendorid from vendorlist";
$db->setQuery($query);
$query = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($query)
{
?>
<div id="dvData">
    <table id="example" border="1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Vendor </th>
        <th>Vendor ID </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    foreach ($query as $res) 
    {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $res->Vendor . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->VendorID . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: "*What do I need to change so that my site displays the same as the demo?*" how can anyone know without seeing your code, and what you are doing...? It is hard to debug an image.

Comment: @davidkonrad - just edit post to show how I populte HTML table